# Difference between first() and filter() in django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have InstituteDetailsModel which have just **one** entry in it. I have another table StudentDetails which is using InstituteDetailsModel as FK in one of its column like below:

```
institute = models.ForeignKey('institute.InstituteDetailsModel', to_field="sys_id", on_delete = models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=True)
```

Now when storing student details I tried to get the only entry from Institute table using below two methods. Second method threw error `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.` while first one worked fine.

I wanted to know what is the difference between

```
InstituteDetailsModel.objects.filter(sys_id=1)
```

&

```
InstituteDetailsModel.objects.first()
```

And why one of them worked and another didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InstituteDetailsModel.objects.filter(sys_id=1)
```

When you doing above this will return Queryset of InstituteDetailsModel

```
 InstituteDetailsModel.objects.first()
```

This will return Instance of InstituteDetailsModel

So you have to fetch data from index in Queryset like

```
 ins = InstituteDetailsModel.objects.filter(sys_id=1)
 ins = ins[0]
```

Now type of `ins`  and `InstituteDetailsModel.objects.first()` are same

If InstituteDetailsModel model don't have any entry then below code will return None

```
InstituteDetailsModel.objects.first()
```

But below will return Blank Queryset

```
InstituteDetailsModel.objects.filter(sys_id=1)
```